# Customized horizontal scrolling content slider having Image Title & Description

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am working on a project in asp.net c#. I need to implement horizontal scrolling content slider having image title & description in the home page.

- Please suggest a good plugin/example
  that can customized to solve my
  problem.

Screen snapshot of my requirement
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/698160fd65.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/698160fd65.jpg)

Comment: I think it is not so difficult to create a horizontal scrolling showcase at all.<br/>
Here is the tutorial to create one by yourself <br/>
http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer this link and made your own Horizontal slider.

[Create a Horizontal Scrolling Website](http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-website.html)

[How To Create a Horizontally Scrolling Site](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/)

[Create a Vertical, Horizontal and Diagonal Sliding Content Website with jQuery](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery)

[24 Superb Sites That Use Horizontal, Vertical Or Multi-Directional jQuery Scrolling Effect](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/06/26/24-superb-sites-that-use-horizontal-vertical-or-multi-directional-jquery-scrolling-effect/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any script or plugin you find it suitable for you website.

Then, put it in a `Literal` or a `Repeater`.